# What can i do if SSL certificate don`t working in IIS, but working in Local

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl

I have two projects: Web Api(back) and MVC(front). Web Api(back) has a method that uses the SSL certificate. If running the Web Api(back) in local, then the method works, but if running Web Api(back) in IIS and send post in MVC(front) to the method, then it catches an error "One or more errors occurred". (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.).
Web Api(back) code

```
public decimal GetIdentification(IdentificationModel identification, int key)
    {
        try
        { 
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"cert\\hgg.p12");
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(path, _certPassword));

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _identityUrl + "iin=" + identification.IIN + "&vendor=" + _vendor))
            {
                string token = GetToken();
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-idempotency-key", "key:" + "hggKey-" + key);
                request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
                //request.Content = new StringContent(identification.Photo);
                request.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(identification.Photo)));
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");

                var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                string data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data).result;
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetIdentification" + e.Message);
        }
    }
    public string GetToken()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "cert\\hgg.p12");
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(path, _certPassword));
        try
        {
            

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _tokenUrl))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic " + _token);
                    request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
                    request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + _username + "&password=" + _password + "&scope=identkey");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).access_token;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetToken" + e.Message + path + " " +_certPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

MVC(front)

```
public string Identity(RequestClass<IdentificationModel> request)
    {            
        ResponseClass<decimal> response = new ResponseClass<decimal>();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var httpResponse =
                    httpClient.PostAsync(_apiUrl + $"Identification", data).Result;
            string responseContent = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            return responseContent;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationPoolIdentity don't have permission for certmgr.msc